# Creating a hovering button on text selection on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a hovering type button near highlighted/selected text on a web page. 
Something like this. This button should appear as soon as someone select some text and disappear when no text is selected. Button should be positioned at the end of selection.

[image]

I am relatively new to web development. I know little bit of JavaScript and html. Please guide me through this. How should I start?

Comment: Please care to comment before downvoting.

Comment: You may use Tool tip such as Jquery Tipsy http://tooltipsy.com/. In bootstrap Tooltip is there http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips but u must configure the functionality inside the tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with catching the mouseup event to get selected text, and creating a hidden div for displaying your options which will be shown only when user selects text. I have created a jsfiddle to help you start : https://jsfiddle.net/zaffer/rmjn7rkx/

The div responsible to show the options :

```
<div id="option" class="arrow_box">
    <div id="copy">
      Copy
    </div>
    <div id="separator"> | </div>
    <div id="speak">
      Speak
    </div>
</div>
```

Script responsible to catch events of selection and displaying options box :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mouseX;
  var mouseY;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseX -= 45;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    mouseY -= 40;
    var selection = "";

    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
    }
    if (selection == "") {
      $("#option").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  function calculatePositionAndDisplay() {
    $('#option').css({
      'top': mouseY,
      'left': mouseX
    }).fadeIn('slow');
  }

  $(document.body).bind('mouseup', function(e) {
    var selection = "";

    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    if (selection.toString() !== '') {
      calculatePositionAndDisplay();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#copy", function() {
    // Copy to clipboard code here
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#speak", function() {
    // Speak code here
  });
});
```

CSS for creating the options box :

```
#option {
  display: none;
  background: #636363;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#8d8d8d, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#8d8d8d, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#8d8d8d, #0d0d0d);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#8d8d8d, #0d0d0d);
  /* Standard syntax */
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 20px;
}

#copy {
  width: 45px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#separator {
  width: 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: left;
}

#speak {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0);
  border-top-color: #0d0d0d;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `window.getSelection()`, check it here http://jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/390/